# Let's consider the inequality $2a^2+b^4+c^4\geq4abc$...

Tags: inequality

Which one of the methods can be used(Even if they are useless) for showing that it will always be correct for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$:

*Suppose that $a+b+c=1$ and look at $a+b+c=0$ after

*Suppose that $abc=1$ and look at $abc=0$ after

*Using the Ravi transformation by posing $a=x+y$, $b=y+z$ and $c=z+x$

*Pose $a=\dfrac{x}{y}$, $b=\dfrac{y}{z}$ and $c=\dfrac{z}{x}$

*Pose $a=x-y$, $b=y-z$ and $c=z-x$

*Suppose that $a\leq y\leq z$

Comment: Is there a mistake somewhere? a=b=c=0 and x=y=z=1 violates $2a^{2}+b^{4}+c^{4} \geq 4xyz$. Typo? Missing constraint? Is do you mean which of those options makes it always true? It isn't clear what you're asking.

Comment: Probably the OP meant $a,b,c$ instead of $x,y,z$.

Comment: That doesn't align with the bullet points, which imply a,b,c should be functions of x,y,z in some way. I'm leaning towards the question being "Which is these makes the inequality true?"

Comment: I meant to put $\geq4abc$

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Why would *any* of those work?  They all have constraints that will not apply for all values.  What if a+b+c equals neither 1 nor 0? Not be the sides of a triangle? Have a product of neither 1 nor 0,???  And if we solve it for your eight cases that certainly isn't exhaustive?  So... what exactly are you asking.

Comment: The answer was no one of them... Thanks to them who found that...

Answer (score 1):

In case you mean $a,b,c$ instead of $x,y,z$:

The techniques you describe do not seem appropriate for this problem. You can prove it as follows:

The AM-GM inequality for $4$ variables states that 
$$\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}{4}≥\left(x_1x_2x_3x_4\right)^{\frac14}$$
for all positive real numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$. With $x_1=x_2=a^2$, $x_3=b^4$ and $x_4=c^4$ we get:
$$\frac{a^2+a^2+b^4+c^4}{4}≥\left(a^2a^2b^4c^4\right)^{\frac14}\iff\\2a^2+b^4+c^4≥4abc
$$